# tuple or data for loading file haskell

Tags: file, haskell, tuples

I have to load a database of the format:

```
"Blade Runner"
"Ridley Scott"
1982
("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)
```

into

```
type Rating = (String, Int)
data Film = Film {  title :: String,
                    director :: String,
                    year :: Int,
                    ratings :: [Rating] } deriving (Read,Show)
```

Would it better to leave Rating as a tuple or change to a data type?
As I will have to save the file as well.

Comment: The format you've given isn't compatible with the generated `Read` and `Show` instances for `Film`, so they won't be useful. You would need to read and write `Film`s specially rather than using the generated instances. The list of ratings will not `read` as `[Rating]` either. It doesn't matter too much whether you use a data type or a tuple as long as what you write to the file is what the `Read` instance expects.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! This have proven to be very useful

Comment: Your life will generally be easier if you nix that tuple. That's just not a good place for one. You should also consider abandoning `read` in favor of something like `attoparsec`.

Comment: @dfeuer for this use, the error messages provided by Parsec or trifecta are probably more important than the speed of attoparsec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(String, Int)` and `data Rating = { name :: String, score :: Int }` are the same — because they are *isomorphic*. The practical difference is one has better field names than the other — i.e. would you rather `fst` and `snd` or `name` and `score`?

This has little to do with reading and writing to files, however. As far as I know there is no appreciable difference between the two in this regard. At the worst, they are isomorphic and so you can convert between the representations.